# complex infinite series reference needed

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, infinite-product

I am an undergraduate student and I am looking for some notes and articles about complex infinite series and power series ,and also some problems . Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Any good book on complex variables cannot but mention at some point complex power series.

Comment: give me some exemples please

Comment: Oh, I didn't bother to specify any since there are many books on complex variables and I thought you'd want one that suited your own tastes. On searching, for example, one finds this one in the link which appears to be good: https://books.google.com.ng/books/about/Complex_Analysis.html?id=kHt3CAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y

Comment: thank you so much